# One or more dropped items were invalid and will not be added to the control - Color Balance Mosaic Dataset

Tags: arcmap, landsat-8, image-mosaic

I am having some issues dropping a processed Landsat 8 image into the Color Balance Mosaic Dataset.  The image has been processed through the following:

1. Atmospheric correction QGIS
2. Pan-sharpening ERDAS
3. Topographic correction ERDAS model maker
4. Cloud/shadow removal using unsupervised classification Arcmap

I have multiple images of the same area.  I removed the cloud/shadow coverage and need to merge my images back into one to get only vegetation coverage.  I read that I can use the color balance mosaic dataset tool to do histogram matching, but it will not open my file.  The file format is `.img`.  I tried saving it as a `.lry`, but I get the same error.  I have also tried browsing to it through the folder button and can open the saved `.img.lry` file, but then get an error "The value is not a Mosaic Layer".

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's an IMG not a mosaic dataset http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-mosaic-dataset.htm . It sounds like you've already done the mosaic in QGIS or ERDAS.. you will probably need to go back a step or two and repeat for each image then create a mosaic dataset in ArcGIS to color balance.

Comment: Are you saying go back a couple steps in my above procedure?

Comment: Yes, to the point where you have individual scenes of Landsat images with which you can create a mosaic dataset. The tool you're trying to use balances the colours of the scenes referenced by a mosaic dataset.. if you have only one scene the Color balance Mosaic Dataset tool will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Okay I understand, but my img file is not one color, it contains 6 bands.  After my above procedures, would saving it as a tiff make a difference?

Comment: It's still one file, IMG or TIFF makes no difference, it's still just one scene. A mosaic dataset is made from a collection of files - usually with the same number of bands, covering *different geographical areas*. Whatever process you're following is intended for an area larger than one scene in an attempt to minimize the difference between scenes.

Comment: okay, I understand.  Thank you for clarifying.  Should I delete my question for it is not relevant?

Comment: No, leave the post, if you were confused about what the tool does there's bound to be someone else who arrives at the same misconception.